# load compressed svg with Snap SVG

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I have:

```
Snap.load(src, function(f){im = canvas.canvasSvg.g(f.select('*'));});
```

Where the variable src holds a direction to a svg file (as in: "resources/foo.svg").
I need to place the loaded svg in a group to access it properly later on. This works perfectly fine.

Now, I'd like to use compressed svg format (svgz). But when src points to a svgz file, ("resources/foo.svgz"), I get the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/x-gzip: "http://localhost:8888/web/resources/foo.svgz".
```

Why is this? And how can I load the compressed foo.svgz into Snap? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this file is coming from a web server, you need to leave the mime-type alone i.e. keep it as image/svg+xml and instead change the Content-Encoding to gzip

If it's a local file you're out of luck as there's no way to indicate to the UA what it is unless the UA natively recognises it and most don't.

Comment: Thanks. The file will be in a web server, but on the same one, basically the same folder, as the page that loads it. Which one of your two options would that fall into?

Comment: The first since that's about web servers.

Comment: Sounds hopeful! I'm not doing anything special, that I know, with the mime-type. Where in my code should I look for the problem? The headers in the php file? The php upload handler (that would be the one from jquery uploader)?

Comment: I'm using MAMP on my development environment. It's apache when it goes into production.

Comment: You'll have to read up on how to set mime-types and content-encoding on those environments.